# SQL query to return sum of column grouped by months including all prior dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to return the balance on an account summarized by month, grouped by account and month. For example, given a transactions table that looks like this:

```
| date       | account_id | trans_amount |
| 2012-01-01 |          1 |        -2500 |
| 2012-01-01 |          2 |        -2500 |
| 2016-01-01 |          1 |         5000 |
| 2016-01-01 |          2 |         5000 |
| 2016-02-01 |          1 |         7500 |
| 2016-02-01 |          2 |         7500 |
```

I'd like the query to return:

```
| month | year | account_id | balance |
| 01    | 2012 |          1 |   -2500 |
| 01    | 2012 |          2 |   -2500 |
| 01    | 2016 |          1 |    2500 |
| 01    | 2016 |          2 |    2500 |
| 02    | 2016 |          1 |   10000 |
| 02    | 2016 |          2 |   10000 |
```

I started with this:

```
SELECT MONTH(date), YEAR(date), account_id, SUM(trans_amount)
FROM transactions
GROUP BY account_id, MONTH(date), YEAR(date);
```

but of course that gives the change during the grouped period, not the balance including transactions prior to the period.

Comment: where is `amount_cents` come from?

Comment: Good catch - should be `trans_amount`. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be a nested query. Something like this:

```
SELECT MONTH(date) as month, YEAR(date) as year, account_id, (select SUM(trans_amount) from transactions t2 where t1.date>=t2.date and t1.account_id = t2.account_id) as balance
FROM transactions t1
GROUP BY account_id, MONTH(date), YEAR(date);
```

You will most likely need to fix the syntax a bit. I'm also not completely sure how well the dates will match up with the grouping so you might need to construct a synthetic date for the inner select.

Comment: Hmm - when I try this, I get  "Expression #4 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'database_name.t1.date' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"

Comment: You can try building a date from the month and year and then use that in the inner select statement. You'll have to work it out from there though. Another option would be to try removing the "group by" initially for example and get it working without that then gradually add the complexity back